# Coding Photoshop UI/UX to fully working website?

Tags: user-interface, adobe, photoshop, user-experience

I am working on a website UI/UX design in Photoshop. The core functions that the website will have are searchable content, adding payment credit card to account, monthly membership payment, payment history and infographics on money spent on website services (like a client service being featured on a search - like www.mobile.de).

My question is: what is the best option to code the website using the UI/UX I design to incorporate the fuctions I need.

To be more exact, I am looking for the site to have animations like this app presentation on the infographics: https://www.behance.net/gallery/45859207/AR-Virtual-Fitness-Coach-App-AR-

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to break your approach in following steps:

1. Get structure of your app (HTML)
2. Gather style details of each of the elements , build a style guide and incorporate the css

Not sure if you would be using css3 for transformation of elements or javascript but can detail more if I could get more idea.